# Android disable message "Process system isn't responding"?

Tags: android, android-notifications, emulation, error-messaging

I have installed Android Studio + emulator. Created virtual device with Android 14, assigned 8 CPU, 6 GB RAM etc. Often it works slow, but it works, and that is enough for me. But some days I get the message "Process system isn't responding" every few seconds. I always click Wait and I can continue. But the message interrupts my work literally every few seconds. It is extremely irritating and takes my time. Can I somehow disable the message in Android?

[image: Android message]

Comment: You can look at Logcat to see why it's crashing...